# Vaadin change Theme

Tags: java, intellij-idea, themes, vaadin

how can I edit the given Themes in Vaadin.

I use IntelliJ Idea to develop my Vaadin-App and want to edit a existing Theme like valo. 
In my project, I haven´t a Folder like VAADIN or Webcontent.

This is my Idea-Project:

[image]

How can i create a scss File to edit the style of my application?
I use Vaadin 7, IntelliJ Idea 15.0.2 and Java 1.7.
To change existing Themes I use

```
@Theme("valo")
public class MyVaadinApplication extends UI {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you read this https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html ? It explains the things you must know and do

Comment: Yes, but:
This first sentence: "Custom themes are placed in the VAADIN/themes folder of the web application, in an Eclipse project under the WebContent folder "
I haven´t a eclipse project or a WebContent Folder.

Comment: So just create the Folderd

Comment: Where ? And How?
Web-Content
|- VAADN 
|--.....
Like this ? or in WEB-INF ?

Comment: Below the web folder. (Uppercase for `VAADIN` is a must)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100421/discussion-between-dominik-and-andre-schild).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to place your custom Theme in web/VAADIN/themes/mytheme
Add a scss file by right clicking the folder mytheme and enter eg. "style.scss".

If you created your Project with Maven you can use the vaadin plugin to compile you scss code properly.

Make sure to read https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-creating.html for further information in how to create your own theme.